LettuceEncrypt: Failed to validate ownership of domainName
I am using the LettuceEncrypt sample application together with ngrok (ngrok http 80) to test Lets Encrypt certificate creation.
fail: LettuceEncrypt.Internal.AcmeCertificateFactory[0]
      Failed to validate ownership of domainName 't79b-149-167-20-95.ngrok-free.app'. Reason: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:tls: x.xxxx:Xxx:Xx: remote error: tls: no application protocol, Code = BadRequest
trce: LettuceEncrypt.Internal.TlsAlpnChallengeResponder[0]
      Clearing ALPN cert for t79b-149-167-20-95.ngrok-free.app
dbug: LettuceEncrypt.Internal.AcmeCertificateFactory[0]
      Validation with TlsAlpn01DomainValidator failed with error: Failed to validate ownership of domainName 't79b-149-167-20-95.ngrok-free.app'
      System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to validate ownership of domainName 't79b-149-167-20-95.ngrok-free.app'
         at LettuceEncrypt.Internal.DomainOwnershipValidator.WaitForChallengeResultAsync(IAuthorizationContext authorizationContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\Desktop\LettuceEncrypt-main\src\LettuceEncrypt\Internal\DomainOwnershipValidator.cs:line 56

my question is how to test the sample application.
